# Generators of twisted affine Lie algebra $D^{(2)}_2$

Tags: lie-algebras

Does anyone know an explicit algebraic definition of the generators of the twisted affine Lie algebra $D^{(2)}_2$?

Comment: Could you please provide a little more background?

Comment: Basically, I just want to know how to go from  $D_2$ to $D^{(2)}_2$. In particular, if I start from the fundamental representation of $D_2$ as skew-symmetric matrices four by four matrices, how a basis of these are modified to give a basis of $D^{(2)}_2$?

Comment: You overestimate my knowledge of your background. Imagine I don't know more than the Wikipedia definition of twisted affine Lie algebras (and maybe I know that $D_2 = A_1 \times A_1$).